# change font in python output

Tags: python, output, printers

I'm starting to code in Python and I just bought a bluetooth printer, I connected it on my raspberry pi and wrote a code to print things on it. I would like to know if it is possible to change the font family and size for example?

Here follows the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python  

import serial  
from time import sleep  

bluetoothSerial = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm0", baudrate=9600)  
testS = "Raspberry-PI Project \nPrinter Test"  
testV = input()  
bluetoothSerial.write(bytes(testS, 'UTF-8'))  
bluetoothSerial.write(bytes(testV, 'UTF-8'))
```

Comment: Please, provide the code for printing.

Comment: Pleas einclude this code *in your question*. It is not comprehensible in the comments

Comment: code already in the text box. i'm sorry guys, this is my first question here. :)